# Owl carousel is not working slider in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, carousel

I want to slider the "dhelp_lite_slider"'s  post thumbnails using owl carousel in wordpress site. I'm calling my guess wrong. I would be glad if you help.

```
function main_slider()
{

    $html = '';
    $slider = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'=> 'dhelp_lite_slider',
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'post_status' => 'private',
        'meta_key' => '_ordering_slider',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',

        
    ));

    $html .= '<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">';
    foreach ( $slider as $post ) {

            //var_dump($post);
$html .= '<div class="item">'.$post->post_title.'</div>';
    }
    $html .= '</div>';

    return $html;

}
add_shortcode( 'main_slider_hook', 'main_slider' );
```